# Installing asus pce-ac51 driver

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to install the wireless pci adapter Asus pce-ac51 on Ubuntu 17.04 because the 5Ghz band is not working on Ubuntu (it works on Windows 10), but when I try to run the sh script I get this error

```
tar: La opción antigua 'f' requiere un argumento
Pruebe 'tar --help' o 'tar --usage' para más información.
install.sh: 25: cd: can't cd to clean
install.sh: 38: [: unexpected operator
install.sh: 48: [: unexpected operator
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c: In function ‘aes_cipher’:
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c:1598:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     ^~~
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c:1601:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘for’
  payload_index = hdrlen + 8;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c: In function ‘aes_decipher’:
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c:1984:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     ^~~
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_security.c:1987:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘for’
  payload_index = hdrlen + 8;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c: In function ‘dump_drv_version’:
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                                ^
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver/core/rtw_debug.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Descargas/PCE-AC51-ASUS_V1.0.0_20160603/linux_driver/driver] Error 2
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with slow upload speed on this card

For fix, reinstall realtek drivers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8821ae
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```